# multiple conda venv , the PATH , the LD_Library_path

Tags: pytorch

In the .bashrc file, there are multiple environment variables set, such as `PATH` and         `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Will virtual environments not automatically recognize these?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch2/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch2/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch20/bin/:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch20/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch20/lib/python3.11/site- 
#export PATH="$HOME/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" # commented out by conda initialize`
export PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch13/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/score_based/bin/:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/jwshi/anaconda3/envs/torch13/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" # commented out by conda initialize
```

is there any other way to solve the multiple virtual environment selecting cuda automatically?`

Comment: Can you format the question properly and more specifically, elaborate the issue you are facing and what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.